# How do I subtract from exiting model if a request is sent from another model?

Tags: python, django, django-views

Am trying to create a withdrawal request, the request sent successfully as expected but it doesn't subtract from the existing balance.

Here's my model.

```
def withdrawals(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        Input_Amount = request.POST['Input_Amount']
        username = request.POST['username']
        input_password = request.POST['password']
        total = Users_Balanc.objects.get(user=request.user)
        
        if Withdrawal_password.objects.filter(username=request.user).exists():
            password = Withdrawal_password.objects.get(username=request.user)
            if password.password3 == input_password:
                if int(Input_Amount) > 100:
                    if (total.Amount >= float(Input_Amount)):
                        New_Request = Request.objects.create(Wallet_Address=password.Wallet_Address, Amount=Input_Amount, user = username)
                        New_Request.save
                        messages.success(request, 'Successful')
                        return redirect('withdrawals')
                    else:
                        messages.warning(request, 'Insufficient funds')
                        return redirect('withdrawals')
                else:
                        messages.warning(request, 'Sorry, your withdrawal is below 100TRX')
                        return redirect('withdrawals')
            else:
                messages.warning(request, 'Sorry, your withdrawal password is not correct')
                return redirect('withdrawals')
        else:
            messages.warning(request, 'Sorry, you haven\'t create a withdrawal password yet.')
            return redirect('withdrawals')
    else:
        balance = Users_Balanc.objects.filter(user=request.user)
        return render(request, 'withdrawals.html', {'balance': balance})
```

Even when I add `total.Amount - Input_Amount` just after `if (total.Amount >= float(Input_Amount))`

Please what's the way around this?

Comment: Can I ask why you aren't using a model form for this?

Comment: Oh I never thought of that since am always using view to manipulate my way around stuff.

Comment: But what difference does it make if am using html form that actually saves my data. Please I need to understand this.

Comment: If you use a django form it will do aot of the heavy work for you, including creating some html snippets you can use directly in templates. It will also return validation errors for all fields at the same time and won't disappear from the message box

Comment: I'd try to use class based views where appropriate too. And I havent found a use case where I cant use one so far, or customise it to suit my needs.

Comment: Keep it classy man :)

Comment: Okay thanks man I’ll see what I can do with this method. I appreciate